# How to check number of arguments is while passing them in CLI?

Tags: java, command-line-interface

A simple program that takes 2 arguments from the commandline and if they're 2, it simply multiplies them, otherwise throws my custom exception.

```java
import java.util.*;

class MyException extends Exception
{
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Something Went Wrong :(";
    }
}

class ExceptionCLI
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int A = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int B = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        
        if() //** Missing condition, what should I write? args[].length < 2 doesn't work**
        {
            try
            {
                throw new MyException();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e.toString());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Result: "+A*B);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried:

1. `args[].length`
2. `int len = args[].length`

I am not that experienced in Java, so I don't know any other methods to try.

Comment: `args.length` is what you need

Comment: Do not use declarations like `String args[]`. Although it works, it is considered bad form to use. Instead use `String[] args`.

Comment: You should check the length of args *before* trying to parse them, otherwise you may get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Answer (score 4):

The `length` attribute is accessed thus:  `args.length`

Example use:

```
if( args.length == 2 ) { … } else { … }
```

The issue isn't really with CLI, but with understanding arrays in Java.

**Some array basics for this example:**

- `String [] args` declares variable `args` to be an array of `String`.
- `String args []` is an alternate way of declaring variable `args` to be an array of `String`.
- So, `args` is a variable. It's type is `String []`, i.e., an array of `String`.
- `args[n]` is an element of that array, i.e., in this case, an individual `String`.
- - `n` may be a constant, variable, or expression.
- - `n` must be resolvable to an `int` type.
- In Java, an array is a reference type. It has the attributes and methods of an `Object`. In addition, it has a `length` attribute.
- `args` is the name of the reference in this example.
- The `length` attribute is accessed thus:  `args.length`
- - Example:  `if (args.length > 100) { System.out.println ("foo"); }`
- `args[]` by itself won't compile. Neither will `args[].foo` where `foo` is an attribute. Neither will `args[].foo()` where `foo` is a method. Again, the name of the variable representing the whole array is `args`, not `args[]`.

**Other comments:**

- Check the length of `args` *before* attempting to parse (an) element(s). It might be `args` is empty. That is,  `args.length` could be zero. If that is the case, `args[0]` won't exist.
- If you don't check the length before parsing an element, you should be prepared for an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.
- If an element exists, but doesn't represent an integer, an attempt to parse can throw a `NumberFormatException`.

Answer (score 0):

> *"How to check number of arguments is while passing them in CLI? ..."*

Your syntax is incorrect.
Instead of *args[]*, use just *args*.

The bracket syntax is only used during declaration, and when accessing an element.
*[Arrays (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Language Basics)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)*.

Additionally, you're attempting to access *args* elements which may not exist.
If *args* has no elements, then these will throw an *[ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html)*.

```java
int A = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
int B = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
```

Check the *args* parameter first.

```java
if(args.length < 2) {
    try
    {
        throw new MyException();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
} else {
    int A = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int B = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    System.out.println("Result: "+A*B);
}
```

Here is an example output with no input.

```
Something Went Wrong :(
```

And, here is an output with *2* and *3* as the input.

```java
Result: 6
```

Comment: Throwing an empty and uninformative custom exception and then immediately catching it is worse than pointless. It's fundamentally wrong. The normal procedure is to print an error/usage message to stderr and exit with an error code

Comment: @g00se, you should write a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is the usual MO:

```
if (args.length < 2) {
   System.err.println("Usage: java ExceptionCLI <number 1> <number 2>");
   System.exit(1);
}
```

If you want to practise with custom exceptions, extend `RuntimeException` and use it in the context of some method other than `main`